# Link issues with fiber card under RHEL 6.2 and hp dl380

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, fiber, hp-proliant

I am having issues getting a HP ProLiant DL380p Gen8 running RHEL 2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64 to see and/or allow the use of a 10GE fiber card.

I can confirm the fiber connection to the router has been thoroughly debugged and works on another device the same running VMware/esxi.

HP has replaced the board, the card (x2 times) and the PCI riser. The cards I've tried are the hp ethernet 10gb2-port 560sfp+ and the HP Ethernet 10Gb 2-port 530SFP+ Adapter. As part of the debug process we've also tried different sfp trancievers(?) but the one I know works on our other devices is champion 10gsfp+e-lr and the one we're using currently. We have also updated the bios and ilo to most current.

I've updated to the current patches of that time from RHEL.

The nic does not show up in HP's iLO and the interfaces in the OS won't get link on the router.

I've been working with hp and rh for several months now trying to trouble shoot this but so far we've not gotten any solid results. I know surely someone has a dl380 running rhel with a fiber card of this type? If not perhaps you could recommend one you know works ;(

Answer (score 0):

A few things to do first would be:

- update to the latest rhel, 6.6 at this time (you mention 6.2)
- update firmware via SPP - also the nic firmware (which you seem to have done)

If the nic is visible on the host it should show up in iLo.
First check that the nic works by using copper sfp's to a switch. 
That should allow you to verify that the basics work. 
Not all cards are supported in all generations of Gen8, but this is something that HP should be able to clarify.

Then it's an open question whether your selected sfp works with the card you have.
Long range transceivers will require more power to work and therefore will not work in every
type of equipment.

Alternatively you could route the traffic via a switch which does work with the transceiver.

That said, I've had few issues with supported cards in FlexibleLOM slots on Gen8 (but we tend to use copper sfp's). There were some overheating problems a few years back, but nothing recent.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll review the 6.6 updates and see if we can apply them to the host.